# 403 error using django_comments

Tags: django, django-forms

I use django_comments as comment system of my site, but when I post the comment, it gives 403 error. Why?

This is my settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)
```

The others forms works well. They won't give 403 error.

Comment: But other forms work well.Why?

Answer (score 2):

Your other forms work because you have disabled the CSRF middleware. This is a bad idea, because it makes your website vulnerable to a CSRF attack.

The [`post_comment`](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments/blob/d1af2be547d1b0c9d2657ea7dcd793b4ac2e7c54/django_comments/views/comments.py#L32) view from django_comments explicitly uses the `csrf_protect` decorator. Therefore, you must include `{% csrf_token %}` in the form tag in your template to prevent CSRF errors.

If you still have problems, then it is probably the view. [As the docs say](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it), you must make sure that the template is rendered with the `request` object, otherwise the `{% csrf_token %}` tag will not work.

Comment: But I use a Third party comment system which is based on based on django_comment.And this is my html code 


`{% load threadedcomments_tags %}
....
<h2>Comments for {{ object.title }}:</h2>
{% render_comment_list for object %}
{% render_comment_form for object %}`


The code in the author's blog work well,but in my website give 403 error,why?

Comment: Your view probably doesn't include the `request` in the template context, so the `csrf_token` tag won't work.

Comment: But I doesn't need  to write views,because you can  use it by including the html code like this,
`{% load threadedcomments_tags %} .... <h2>Comments for {{ object.title }}:</h2> {% render_comment_list for object %} {% render_comment_form for object %}`
In terms of the `request` I don't know where should I include.
BTW,I download the comment by using pip.

Comment: Show the view where you use the comment form. I can't help you otherwise.

Comment: This is where I find the third party comment system.Here is the url:
http://answ.me/post/comment-in-django-part-1/

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you, **because you have not shown your view**.  Linking to other websites doesn't help, especially when it's in a different language.